# Bootbox: Message is Overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I'm using the latest version of Bootbox and need to display a very large amount of text.  The text is overflowing out of the Bootbox modal window and off the browser.  I need the text contained and with a vertical scrollbar when appropriate.  I've tried wrapping the message in various html elements, but no luck.

Here's my code:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    onEscape: function () { },
    message: JSON.stringify(data),
    title: "View",
    buttons: {
        main: {
          label: "Cancel",
          className: "btn-default",
          callback: function () {
             //close popup and do nothing
             return true;
          }
       }
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dqud8kg7/7/)**

Comment: Demo updated with long content. It seems like Bootbox handles it gracefully, extending the modal as required. See if you can replicate your problem.

Comment: @isherwood...I used your <p>text</p> and it works perfectly.  When I update it to "<p>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "</p>", not good.  In this case 'data' is just a big json object.  I wonder how that would effect this?

Comment: @isherwood...I updated it with the json data (also tried adding quotes around it too)

Comment: Oops. Deleted earlier comment by mistake. Here's the initial fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dqud8kg7/

Comment: @isherwood...it's there now

Comment: @isherwood...Sorry, but I can't get yours to work - I rarely use Fiddle.  Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/BigDaddy/fx8s63cu/5/

Comment: It's broken. 404s on all your external resources. Just put your JSON in my fiddle and hit Update. Copy the URL.

Comment: @isherwood...done, thank for your patience :)

Comment: And... post the URL.

Comment: @isherwood...http://jsfiddle.net/BigDaddy/dqud8kg7/6/

Comment: You have a pile of double quotes in your JSON, which terminates the string value of `message`.

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dqud8kg7/7/

Comment: @isherwood...thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data is one long string, which forces the paragraph element to exceed normal width unless you specify word breaks.

```
.modal-body p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dqud8kg7/8/)**

**[Longer demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dqud8kg7/9/)**

Answer (score 0):

For when including table you may use following,

```
.bootbox-body table{
    width:100% !important;
}
```